# Handling Multiple Users sending commands

Tags: python, discord.py

On my bot I have this command inside a cog that using pytube, downloads a video and a video's audio, and then uses moviepy to join the both and then send it off to the user.
The problem is that while it's processing that command, the bot stops listening for any other commands that may be sent.

I don't  have a clue on how to fix it nor if it also applies to regular commands.

```
import discord
import os
import moviepy.editor as mpe
from pytube import YouTube, exceptions

@commands.command(name='mp4', aliases=['ytmp4'])
    async def mp4(self, ctx, link=None, resolution='720p'):

        def combine_audio(vidname, audname, outname, vid_fps):
            vid_clip = mpe.VideoFileClip(vidname)
            aud_clip = mpe.AudioFileClip(audname)
            final_clip = vid_clip.set_audio(aud_clip)
            final_clip.write_videofile(outname, fps=vid_fps)

        def mp4tomp3(file):
            base, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            file_mp3 = base + '.mp3'
            os.rename(file, file_mp3)

        if link is None:
            await ctx.send('You must include a link!')
        else:
            try:
                yt = YouTube(link)
            except Exception or exceptions.VideoUnavailable:
                await ctx.send('Video is unavailable or not valid.')
            else:
                if yt.streams.filter(res=resolution, only_video=True).first() is None:
                    await ctx.send('That video doesn\'t have that resolution!')
                else:
                    try:
                        await ctx.send(f'Converting Video: `{yt.title}` by `{yt.author}` at `{resolution}`')
                        invalids = [
                            '"', '*', '<', '>', ',', '?', '\\', '|', '/', ':', 'CON', 'PRN', 'AUX', 'NUL', 'COM1', 'COM2',
                            'COM3',
                            'COM4', 'COM5', 'COM6', 'COM7', 'COM8', 'COM9', 'LPT1', 'LPT2', 'LPT3', 'LPT4', 'LPT5', 'LPT6',
                            'LPT7', 'LPT8', 'LPT9'
                        ]
                        vid_title = yt.title
                        fps = yt.streams.filter(res=resolution, only_video=True).first().fps
                        for char in vid_title:
                            if char in invalids:
                                vid_title = vid_title.replace(char, '')

                        yt.streams.filter(res=resolution, only_video=True).first().download(
                            'C:\\Users\\santi\\PycharmProjects\\DiscordBot\\temp', 'vid')
                        mp4tomp3(yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(
                            'C:\\Users\\santi\\PycharmProjects\\DiscordBot\\temp\\', 'aud'))

                        combine_audio(r'C:\Users\santi\PycharmProjects\DiscordBot\temp\vid.mp4',
                                      r'C:\Users\santi\PycharmProjects\DiscordBot\temp\aud.mp3',
                                      f'C:\\Users\\santi\\PycharmProjects\\DiscordBot\\temp\\{vid_title}.mp4', fps)

                    except exceptions.PytubeError or AttributeError:
                        await ctx.send('That video doesn\'t have that resolution!')
                    else:
                        if os.stat(
                                f'C:\\Users\\santi\\PycharmProjects\\DiscordBot\\temp\\{vid_title}.mp4').st_size > 8000000:
                            print(os.stat(f'C:\\Users\\santi\\PycharmProjects\\DiscordBot\\temp\\{vid_title}.mp4').st_size)
                            await ctx.send(
                                'Video file is too large (More than 8MB)! Please download at a lower resolution!')

                        else:
                            await ctx.send('Done!',
                                           file=discord.File(
                                               f'C:\\Users\\santi\\PycharmProjects\\DiscordBot\\temp\\{vid_title}.mp4'))
                        os.remove(f'./temp/{vid_title}.mp4')
                        os.remove(f'./temp/vid.mp4')
                        os.remove(f'./temp/aud.mp3')
```

Comment: Maybe just somewhere build in an `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)` so in that time it can shortly handle other messages. (The important thing is an asynchronous function (`await ...`) in there so it can in that time handle some other messages, reactions,...)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that those modules aren't made to work asynchronous.

For that, I mostly use `bot.loop.create_task()`, as it puts it in the background instead of wait for it to finish.

An example would be:

```py
bot.loop.create_task(runFunction(ctx)) # Inside the command.

# And outside of it
async def runFunction(ctx):
   # Do what u gotta do
```

In your case it requires some more params but that's an example.

Still what you are doing there is a huge process so it still might make some problems there.

For stuff like video or image editing, I would recommend switching to javascipt/node.

Comment: I didn't really understand how to do it. Could you just add some code so I can understand it better? And i don't know if this changes anything but I'm using discord.py rewrite inside a cog